--add-host option does not work in docker
I have two servers with the same operating system (OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64) and both run Docker (Docker version 24.0.7, build 24.0.7-0ubuntu2~22.04.1). I'm trying to access host web-services from inside a container. I followed the instructions from https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#add-host and used the "hello from host" example. On one system, it works; however, on another server, it fails to access the web-server.
Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thank you.
docker info
Client:
 Version:    24.0.7
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 88
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 88
 Images: 26
 Server Version: 24.0.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-119-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.746GiB
 Name: beamish
 ID: dc8ba74f-07f6-4561-a227-ed950578027c
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

Edited:
Hi @DavidMaze
I am trying to reproduce "hello from host!" example at docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#add-host.
I expect
hello from host!

in command line when I run
$docker run \
  --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway \
  curlimages/curl -s host.docker.internal:8000/hello

However, I get no output. The command halts for a while.
Furthermore, for the same command. I get the expected output on a different server with same Ubuntu version installed.
I want to know why the same command is behaving differently on two different systems.
I hope, my query is clear now.
@HansKilian - as you can see above, I had made changes in my command.
Thank you, both.

You don't seem to have provided any details on what you're actually doing; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The docker info version and diagnostic information is not especially useful to diagnose most problems, and it should be okay to remove it from the question.  In the abstract I'd find it pretty unusual to need the docker run --add-host option at all, but without more details it's hard to say more.

A couple of comments regarding the example: If you run the python command as shown, it'll run in the foreground and you won't be able to run the rest of the commands without terminating python.  I also get an error if I use the --add-host option as shown. If I use --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway (with a colon instead of the equals sign) it works. I'm on Docker 24.0.4.

@DavidMaze, I have edited my query. Thank you.

The issue was with UFW. I have resolved with help of https://superuser.com/questions/1709013/enable-access-to-host-service-with-ubuntu-firewall-from-docker-container
